# Getting log in information - how does this code work?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I found a similar question here that someone wanted to create a user account loggin similar to this, but it lead me to believe it has to be all done in php in order to handle it and put into a MySQL database. From my understanding this isn't php and it is on the main html website.

How is the data captured and then stored on a database with this code then?

This is taken directly form http://cardoneuniversity.com/

```
<span class="dominate-and-login-form-text">Already a member?</span>
<form action="https://login.lightspeedvt.com/actions.cfm?lg=447&amp;v=35" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
  <div class="form-group username-field">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputUser3">Username</label>
    <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUser3" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group password-field">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default login-univ-btn">Login</button>
  <br>
  <a href="http://login.lightspeedvt.com/forgot_password.cfm?lg=21" class="forgot-password"><i>Forgot Username/Password?</i></a>
</form>
```

If I seem like nothing more then an uneducated lost programmer, can you care to send me in the direction to learn?

I'm trying to create a learning/course website like this one.

Comment: In your copied example you only have html. PHP isnt visible in the naked browser, though it might be possible to view somehow, but I havent tried it, nor do I need it. Google `php work with mysql` you should find some tutorials that fit your needs. Also take a close look for security, Passwords are always vulnerable data.

Comment: I was actually concerned about security as well. This is my other side of this though, so the browser see's the html and the login form. The php script's that I found I'm not totally sure how to implement them, because from what I found they seem to be the similar to the html form.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this form is processed by ColdFusion. ColdFusion does a similar job to PHP where it is a server side scripting language. Here is a good tutorial that will teach the basics of a login system using HTML, MySQL and PHP.

[User Membership With PHP](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/user-membership-with-php--net-1523)

For a more advanced and secure tutorial check this out:

[How to Create a Secure Login Script in PHP and MySQL](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

Comment: This is great! Thanks! I'll defiantly play around with this and get back to you if I have figured it all out.